# How to target react compunents from a map list using useRef

Tags: reactjs, keypress, use-ref

I'm tring to make few buttons that corresponds to keyboard keys , But i'm fairly new to React and i don't know how to target those elements ,Each element have it's id and i can access the event key but after that i'm lost ,I alredy tried using refs but i didn't find an example that i can work with or understand how can i turn it to use inside my code.
This is the array of objects im using to genrate a list of compunents:

```js
   const [bankOne,setBankOne] = React.useState([
    {
      keyCode: 81,
      keyTrigger: "Q",
      id: "Heater-1",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"
    },
    {
      keyCode: 87,
      keyTrigger: "W",
      id: "Heater-2",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3"
   }]);
```

this is the event handler:

```js
  const handleKeyPress = React.useCallback((event) => {
    //console.log(event.key.toUpperCase());
    console.log(itemsRef.current)
   }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, [handleKeyPress]);
```

this is the list im using to genrate React compunents:

```js
  const bank1 = bankOne.map((item,i) => (
    <button
      ref={el => itemsRef.current[i] = item.keyTrigger}
      id={item.id}
      className="drum-pad"
      value={item.keyTrigger}
      onClick={handleClick}
      onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
    >
      <audio  src={item.url} className="clip" id={item.keyTrigger}>
        <source src={item.url} type="audio/mp3" />
      </audio>
      {item.keyTrigger}
    </button>
  ));
```

i have no idea how to do this ,that's why i didn't post any of the ways i tried to solve the problem because i know they were all wrong one way or another .
i really appreciate any help ,and thank you all.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do. Please describe what should happen from the user's perspective.

Comment: so i'm making a drum machine ,a project for FCC ,each button should be connected to key on the keyboard and when that key is pressed that button should be pressed and the audio element inside of it should play as well

Answer (score 0):

so i learned that i only needed a useRef array and then i targeted each button by it's index in that array,maybe not the best solution but at least it worked .

```js
  const btnsRef = React.useRef([]);
    const handleKeyPress = React.useCallback((event) => {
   switch(event.key.toUpperCase()){
      case "Q":
        btnsRef.current[0].focus()
        btnsRef.current[0].firstChild.load()
        btnsRef.current[0].firstChild.play()
       setData(prev => ({...prev,currentNote: btnsRef.current[0].id}))
        break;
        case "W":
        btnsRef.current[1].focus()
        btnsRef.current[1].firstChild.load()
        btnsRef.current[1].firstChild.play()
       setData(prev => ({...prev,currentNote: btnsRef.current[1].id}))
        break;
}
   }, []);
```

```js
  const component = obj.map((item,index) => (
    <button
      ref={(element) => btnsRef.current[index] = element}
      id={item.id}
      value={item.keyTrigger}
      onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
    >
      <audio className="clip" id={item.keyTrigger}>
        <source src={item.url} type="audio/mp3" />
      </audio>
      {item.keyTrigger}
    </button>
  ));
```